# How to filter a tree structure while keeping the decendants of the parents that are filtered out?

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter, tree

so I have the following tree structure:

```js
const tree = {
  id: "1",
  tag: "pending",
  subtasks: [
    { id: "2", tag: "pending", subtasks: [] },
    {
      id: "3",
      tag: "in progress",
      subtasks: [
        {
          id: "4",
          tag: "pending",
          subtasks: [
            {
              id: "6",
              tag: "in progress",
              subtasks: [
                {
                  id: "10",
                  tag: "pending",
                  subtasks: [{ id: "11", tag: "complete", subtasks: [] }]
                }
              ]
            },
            { id: "7", tag: "complete", subtasks: [] }
          ]
        },
        { id: "5", tag: "pending", subtasks: [] }
      ]
    },
    { id: "4", tag: "complete", subtasks: [] }
  ]
};
```

and I want to remove any node that has the "in progress" `tag`. But, I also want to keep the children of the removed node if their `tag`s are not "in progress" out. They will be kept by moving them to the same depth and index levels of their parent.

so, the result will look something like this:

```js
const filteredTree = {
  id: "1",
  tag: "pending",
  subtasks: [
    { id: "2", tag: "pending", subtasks: [] },
    {
      id: "4",
      tag: "pending",
      subtasks: [
        {
          id: "10",
          tag: "pending",
          subtasks: [{ id: "11", tag: "complete", subtasks: [] }]
        },
        { id: "7", tag: "complete", subtasks: [] }
      ]
    },
    { id: "5", tag: "pending", subtasks: [] },
    { id: "4", tag: "complete", subtasks: [] }
  ]
};
```

how can I achieve that?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove by checking `tag` and take either the filtered `subtasks` or a new object with filtered `subtasks`.

```js
const
    remove = tag => ({ subtasks, ...node }) => {
        subtasks = subtasks.flatMap(remove(tag));
        return node.tag === tag
            ? subtasks
            : [{ ...node, subtasks }]
    },
    tree = { id: "1", tag: "pending", subtasks: [ { id: "2", tag: "pending", subtasks: [] }, { id: "3", tag: "in progress", subtasks: [{ id: "4", tag: "pending", subtasks: [{ id: "6", tag: "in progress", subtasks: [{ id: "10", tag: "pending", subtasks: [{ id: "11", tag: "complete", subtasks: [] }] }] }, { id: "7", tag: "complete", subtasks: [] }] }, { id: "5", tag: "pending", subtasks: [] }] }, { id: "4", tag: "complete", subtasks: [] }] },
    result = remove('in progress')(tree);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: works as intended, thank you for your friendly communication! :)